# can't increase gcache.size galera cluster mariadb

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

i wanted to increase the value of gcache.size on my 3 nodes of the mariadb galera cluster (galera v25.3.22(r3764), mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.33 -
 MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1), from the standard 128MB to 1G.

I have sufficient space on my disk.

I shutdown all 3 nodes, change the parameter in the my.cnf:

```
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=1G"
```

restart the nodes, but the size stays same (on disk as in the wsrep_provider_options).

is this a bug?

I can for example change these 2 parameters without problem:

```
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.recover=yes"

wsrep_provider_options="gcache.page_size=1G"
```

but the gcache.size doesnt increase

Comment: It might be better to ask this question at: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you put that into the `[mysqld]` section of my.cnf?  You should be able to do it one node at a time ("rolling restart"), thereby having zero downtime.

Comment: I put the question now also in de dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: putting it in the mysqld section didnt change anything

Comment: if I leave out the other
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.recover=yes"
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.page_size=1G"
from .my.cnf it works!  my galera.cache changes to the size i want.